# Django - How to show Full name of the Month in Django Admin Panel

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to show Full month (like April or September) in Django Admin Panel. But it keeps show me first 3 letter of the month or a number.
Is there any way to do make it show full month on Admin Panel? Thanks!

PS: The date format I want is like `04 December 2023`

[image]
[image]

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Todo)
class TodoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("id","title","due_date",)
    list_display_links = ("title",)

    def due_date(self,obj):
        return obj.date.strftime("%d %B %Y")
```

**models.py**

```
class Todo(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  due_date = models.DateField()

  def __str__(self):
      return self.title
```

**settings.py**

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-gb'
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Jakarta'
USE_I18N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

**Python version**

```
3.11.1
```

**Django version**

```
4.2
```

Comment: its correct way.`return obj.date.strftime("%d %B %Y")` still not working?

Comment: i tried with your same code. its working `April 5, 2023`

Comment: it should work. have you saved the file?

Comment: @HemalPatel It's didn't work on me it keeps show me `04 Dec 2023`.

Comment: @djangodeveloper It didn't. I even try to change the Language code to `en-gb` in **settings.py** . Still have the same output

Comment: Is there anything wrong in my **settings.py** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that `due_date` field cannot be overriden with the same function name. I have to change it to different function name, and put description and django admin default filter functionality manually back

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Todo)
class AdminTodo(admin.ModelAdmin):  
    list_display = ('id','title','admin_due_date',)
    list_display_links = ('title',)

    # display table header as due_date instead of admin_due_date
    @admin.display(description='due_date')
    def admin_due_date(self,obj):
       return obj.due_date.strftime("%d %B %Y")

    # set django admin filter functionality back
    admin_due_date.admin_order_field = 'due_date'
```